# Script to parse files and make symbolic links

Tags: python, subprocess

In one directory (I will call it input_directory)I've got different files from genomic and transcriptomic data from Illumina sequencing. I only need to parse the files that are from genomic data and make a symbolic link to another directory (I will call it out_directory) to get the files I only need. For this, I have a file with the IDs I'm looking for. These IDs don't end with _1.fastq.gz or _2.fastq.gz as the ones in input_directory. Now, the problem is that I don't get retrieved anything, nor an error message nor an output. 
Hope you could help me out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
from sys import argv

input_directory = "/hosts/b/"
out_directory = "/hosts/a/"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(argv[1], "r") as file_one:
        content_one = file_one.readlines()
        q = [i.split("\r") for i in content_one]
        #print(q)
        for word_i in  q:
            for fileR1 in os.listdir(input_directory):
                l = fileR1.split("_")[0]
                #print(l)
                if l == word_i:
                    out = subprocess.check_output("ln -s" + " " + inputdirectory + l + "*" + " " + out_directory \
                    , shell= True)
```

I ran the code again:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
from sys import argv

input_directory = "/hosts/b/"
out_directory = "/hosts/a/"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(argv[1], "rU") as file_one:
        content_one = file_one.readlines()
        #print(content_one)
        q = [i.split("\n")[0] for i in content_one]
        #print(q)
        for word_i in  q:
            for fileR1 in os.listdir(input_directory):
                l = fileR1.split("_")[0]
                if l == word_i:
                    out = subprocess.check_output("ln -s" + " " + input_directory + l + "*" + " " +  out_directory, shell= True)
```

However, when I ran it, I got the message below.

```
/hosts/a/:python Kita_try1.py genomics.txt 
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/hosts/a/SRR4209894_1.fastq.gz': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/hosts/a/SRR4209894_2.fastq.gz': File exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Kita_try1.py", line 21, in <module>
    out = subprocess.check_output("ln -s" + " " + input_directory + l + "*" + " " +  out_directory, shell= True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ln -s /hosts/b/SRR4209894* /hosts/a/' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I changed it so if the file already exists the loop can continue

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
from sys import argv

input_directory = "/hosts/b/"
out_directory = "/hosts/a/"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(argv[1], "rU") as file_one:
        content_one = file_one.readlines()
        #print(content_one)
        q = [i.split("\n")[0] for i in content_one]
        #print(q)
        for word_i in  q:
            for fileR1 in os.listdir(input_directory):
                l = fileR1.split("_")[0]
                if fileR1 in out_directory:
                    continue
                    if l == word_i:
                        out = subprocess.check_output("ln -s" + " " + input_directory + l + "*" + " " +  out_directory, shell= True)
```

but again I don't get any message or output back.

Comment: This line looks a bit odd here: `q = [i.split("\r") for i in content_one]`. Are you dealing with an ID file that was created on a Windows machine?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Don’t use `readlines()` if you’re going to iterate over all of them sequentially anyway. Just iterate over the file object.

Comment: @user727089 I got surprised when I saw "\r", because in my short coding experience I've never seen it; however, this is what I got when I print content_one:['SRR4209894\rSRR4209895\rSRR4209896\r] and when I print q: [['SRR4209894', 'SRR4209895', 'SRR4209896']]

Comment: This looks like you're indeed dealing with a file created on a Windows system, which makes sense since Illumina uses Windows with its sequencers. The handling of those kind of files depends on the Python version you're running. Which one are you using?

Comment: @user727089 Python 2.7.16. When I use Python 2 I don't get anything, but when I activate Anaconda3 I get an error:                                                           
    File "Kita_try1.py", line 12
    q = [i.split("\r") for i in content_one]
                                           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Oh, yeah. The TabError hits all beginners of Python at some point... Make sure you have your editor set such that it extends TABs to spaces and always use the same indentation (e.g. 2 spaces or 4 spaces).

Comment: In Python 2, when you open a file using a different style of line endings (as Windows does), you can use `open(filename, 'rU')`. But in Python 3 that operator has been deprecated, as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @AlexanderCécile thank you for your comment. I was trying to follow your advice, but I find it difficult to see what it's going on with each file as only the last file is showed to the screen.

Comment: Thank you, @user727089. The code is working. I just need to change a few more things so the code doesn't get stuck when the file already exists.

Comment: So now, with your latest edits, are all symbolic links being created? You wouldn't expect any console output from your script, since there are no `print` statements.

Comment: Now I got permission denied. This is the message:                                    /bin/sh: 2: /hosts/b/: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genomics_sufijos.py", line 15, in <module>
    out = subprocess.check_output("ln -s -f" + " " + input_directory + q  + " " +  out_directory, shell= True)
  File "/home/silviav/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/silviav/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)